# Calling a Function from ForEach in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have this simple button inside a ForEach that calls a function and updates the selected property with the index from the array.

Issue is, the clicked value does not get updated when the button is tapped. If I remove the ForEach and just call function manually then it works. What am I doing wrong?

```
let items: [String] = ["string1","string1"]

struct Tester: View {
    @State var clicked: Int = 0

    func itemView(at index: Int) -> some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.clicked = index

        }) {
            Text("Button \(index) + \(clicked)" )
        }
    }

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<items.count) { index in
                self.itemView(at: index)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code above is working just fine.

Comment: Second button when tapped should be Button 1 + 1 is what I'm expecting. Did that work for you?

Comment: I see nothing wrong, it starts `0 + 0` for the first button and `1 + 0` for the second when I tap the second button, the first becomes `0 + 1` and the second `1 + 1`. If that is all your code, it should work just fine.

Comment: Try your code in a real device or an emulator, it works.

Comment: strange, code does not work for me in the SwiftUI preview but works on the simulator. The original code I referred it from does not work from the simulator at all. [link] (https://github.com/smartvipere75/bottombar-swiftui/blob/master/Sources/BottomBar-SwiftUI/BottomBar.swift)